# How to Check for and raise an error for no command line argument

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary, import, argparse

I have an argparsing program:

import argparse

```
def main():
    p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    help_str = {'rule': 'Blah blah blah and stuff.'}
    p.add_argument('-r', '--rule', action="store", type=str, dest='rule', help=help_str['rule'])
    p.set_defaults(rule='string')
    args = p.parse_args()
```

Therefore, my command line input:

```
username@compname:~$python progname.py -r/--rule 'something'
```

I am trying to figure out how I could just input:

```
username@compname:~$python progname.py -r/--rule
```

and have my own error message come up:

```
print '\n    Error: no input value for rule:'
print '    resetting rule to default value.'
args.rule = 'string'
```

after this, the rule value should print out as 'string'

I am only slightly fluent in Python, sorry.  I have tried using try/except blocks and even sys.argv[2] (though I may have done something wrong.)  This is the error that keeps popping up with all of my solutions (not very familiar with errors outside Type and Value):

```
progname.py: error: argument -r/--rule: expected one argument
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: nvrmnd, solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('-r', '--rule', nargs='?', default='string')
args = p.parse_args()
print args
```

with `nargs='?'` produces `Namespace(rule='string')` if called without argument.  With `-r`, args is `Namespace(rule=None)`.  And `Namespace(rule='something')` with `-r something`.

Lets add a few lines of code

```
if args.rule is None:
    print '\n    Error: no input value for rule:'
    print '    resetting rule to default value.'
    args.rule = 'string'
print args
```

Now the output with '-r' (or `--rule`) is:

```
Namespace(rule=None)

    Error: no input value for rule:
    resetting rule to default value.
Namespace(rule='string')
```

the other cases are the same.

If I drop the `default`; `p.add_argument('-r', '--rule', nargs='?')`, the no argument case also produces this custom 'error message', since the default (in argparse) is `None`.

It's possible to add custom error checking with a custom `type` or `action`, but I think testing for `None` after using `argparse` is simpler, and easier to understand.

I'd suggest changing this `error message` to a `warning`.  An Error usually terminates the program; a warning prints the message and continues.

---

Here's a solution when `nargs=2` (or something else that's fixed).  It's not a trivial change, since it involves redefining the `error` method (documented near the end of the `argparse` docs), and then capturing the error that it produces.  The `error` method cannot access the Namespace (args), nor can it continue `parse_args`.  So it cannot handle any other arguments if there is problem with the `rule` argument.

```
class MyParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def error(self, message):
        if 'rule' in message:
            message = 'wrong number of input values for rule'
            raise argparse.ArgumentError(None,message)
            # cannot access namespace or continue parsing
        else:
            super(MyParser, self).error(message)

p = MyParser()
p.add_argument('-r', '--rule', nargs=2)
try:
    args = p.parse_args()
except argparse.ArgumentError as e:
    print e
    args = argparse.Namespace(rule='default')
    # create a namespace with this default value
print args
```

---

Keep in mind that `nargs` has 2 purposes:
- raise an error if a wrong number of argument strings is given
- allocate multiple argument strings among multiple Actions (the thing created by `add_argument`).

The 2nd is especially evident if you have, for example, several positionals, taking 1,2 and * arguments respectively.  It is a key novel feature of argparse, at least relative to earlier Python parsers.  While it possible to tweak it, it is hard to completely redefine it.

If the arguments allow it, you could use `nargs='*'` instead of the '?', and issue the warning if the number of strings is not '2' (or whatever).

Comment: Thanks, this was driving me nuts.  what if you already have a narg statement with a necessary number value? Is there a workaround?

Comment: I have added a partial solution that redefines the `parser.error` method.